# How to setup static IP in Ubuntu Server 12.04?

Tags: networking, server, configuration

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

1. `ifconfig`
2. `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

   ```
   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.1.150
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   network 192.168.2.0
   broadcast 192.168.1.255
   gateway 192.168.2.1
   safe
   ```
3. `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

   ```
   Do not edit this file by hand --your changes will be overwritten
   # I add this 
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   nameserver 8.8.4.4
   ```
4. `sudo apt-get remove dhcp-client`
5. `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

   ```
   *Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may 
   not enable again some interfaces
   *Reconfiguring network interfaces...
   ssh stop/waiting
   ssh start/running,process 1438
   ```

Where is the mistake? I'm not lazy. I Googled it for 3 days but without results. I tried everything.

After reboot the `/etc/resolv.conf` file is flashing to the original state.

Comment: Hmm any idea why you don't just do everything within the /etc/network/interfaces configuration folder like here: http://draalin.com/setting-up-a-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu/ Or does it make more sense to actually split things up like you did within the resolv.conf and interfaces configuration folder?

Comment: I did it by directly going to the networks tab and editing it manually

Answer (score 16):

This has two independent questions:

**`resolv.conf` entries getting reset after a reboot**

The way `/etc/resolv.conf` working has been changed in Ubuntu 12.04.  This is because of implementation of `foundations-p-dns-resolving`
 as described here 
https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/foundations-p-dns-resolving to overcome some limitations of static `resolv.conf`.

Here you can get more details:
http://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/

You can override the new feature by removing the symbolic link `/etc/resolv.conf` and create a file named `/etc/resolv.conf` there. But before doing that refer the link I given above and see why it is strongly discouraged.

**IP Address Vs Network and Gateway Conflict (Setting up a static IP)** 
Also, As [pgschk](https://askubuntu.com/users/78830/pgschk) pointed out, your IP address is not matching gateway and network entries. But that is not causing the `/etc/resolv.conf` to go to original state, but the reason I mentioned above.

Comment: pardon me error when writing I have 2 servers ,detail as possible removing the symbolic link /etc/resolv.conf and create a file named /etc/resolv.conf there. I've never done this before.PLEASE

Comment: I would suggest to review if any other work around listed in stgraber.org link other than removing symbolic link works for you first. But if you still like to remove the link, you can use, usual commands like 'mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.ori' or 'rm /etc/resolv.conf' and then create a new /etc/resolv.conf using your favourite text editor(like vi or nano).

Comment: I hope you intended /etc/resolv.conf, not /etc/resolv.config in the above question

Comment: I'm online,it's just a bug.thank you,and about remove the link>resolvconfig :Error /etc/resolv.conf isn't a symlink,not doing anything.

Answer (score 6):

Your gateway address is in a different subnet than your local IP address:

address 192.168.**1**.150
gateway 192.168.**2**.1

Also, the network address was specified in the .2 subnet also:

network 192.168.**2**.0

Do you use the 192.168.1/24 or the 192.168.2/24 subnet?

**Edit:**
About your resolv.conf:
This file is mainly updated by different packages (depending on your setup). Try specifying the nameservers in your /etc/network/interfaces file:

`dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`

Comment: sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
address 192.168.1.13
netmask 255.255.255.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.225
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
dns-search mydomaine google.com

Comment: same problem      *Running /etc/init.d/networking resrtart is deprecated because it may 
not enable again some interfaces
*Reconfiguring network interfaces...

Comment: *Running /etc/init.d/networking resrtart is deprecated because it may 
not enable again some interfaces
*Reconfiguring network interfaces...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this option :

- Remove the `/etc/resolv.conf` and then creat a new `resolv.conf`.
- `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf` after that add the flag:
- `sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` - with this `+i` flag, even root can't touch this file. But if you want to change the nameserver, change the flag to be:
- `sudo chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf` then add your new `nameserver`.

Then try to reboot and see what happens :).

I hope this solves your problem.