# How do I configure network interfaces after installing a basic command-line system?

Tags: command-line, networking, wireless, lubuntu, ethernet

I have installed a basic command-line system and didn't configure networking at setup time. Namely, I have booted from [Lubuntu 14.04 Alternate CD](https://web.archive.org/web/20190322031747/http://cdimage.ubuntu.com:80/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04.1-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent), pressed <kbd>F4</kbd> and selected 'Install a command-line system'.

Now I only have the loopback interface configured:

```
$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:50121 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:50121 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4381349 (4.3 MB)  TX bytes:4381349 (4.3 MB)
```

I know my hardware (both `eth0` and `wlan0` interfaces) works ok if I just install the default Ubuntu image with a graphical installer.

How do I configure wired and wireless network interfaces after installing a basic command-line system?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup static IP in Ubuntu Server 12.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180925/how-to-setup-static-ip-in-ubuntu-server-12-04)

Comment: And http://askubuntu.com/q/346838/158442

Answer (score 1):

`cat /proc/net/dev` to get the list of available interfaces (most likely you'll have `eth0` and `wlan0`). Then `ifup` the interface via `sudo ifconfig eth0 up`. You may need to run `sudo dhclient eth0` once the interface is up to get an IP address.

For wireless interface, after `ifup`, you'll need Network Manager to configure it to connect to a given AP.

---

Also if static IP is needed, then I normally used these commands to setup the interface:

`sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.118`

`sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf` # then add a line `nameserver 192.168.0.1` in that file

`sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

You need to read this: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration

It helps out with learning what you need to do for what.